# How to make the NSCollectionView reload data?

Tags: macos, key-value-observing, nscollectionview

I create an NSCollectionView using cocoa binding.I find that when the `NSMutableArray` ,which is set as the `NSCollectionView`'s content ,  finish to sort,the `NSCollectionView` has no change.
Here is my sort code:

```
-(void)updateOrder
{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"bookmarksArray"];
    [_bookmarksArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    /**
     Here is the sort code.
     **/

    }];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"bookmarksArray"];
}
```

I can catch the removed change and inserted change,but I can't catch the reorder change.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not actually change the order. `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` returns a whole new array. It doesn't sort an existing array in place. The sorting operation is effectively thrown away -- `_bookmarksArray` is never changed.  You could, for instance, change it to:

```
-(void)updateOrder
{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"bookmarksArray"];
    _bookmarksArray = [_bookmarksArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    /**
     Here is the sort code.
     **/

    }];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"bookmarksArray"];
}
```

(Assuming ARC here. Same idea but with appropriate `retain`/`release` calls if not ARC.)

Comment: The problem has been solved.I use the NSSortDescriptor.I try to your method.But your method is still the same result with my original problem.

Comment: According to your said "It doesn't sort an existing array in place",I think it's the answer.